# Getting error : the request for member 'at' in 'data', which is of non-class type 'const char*'| error

Tags: c++, debugging, codeblocks

I am trying to set the clipboard data based of some conditions by first checking the string length and the the first character of the string in the clipboard. If this returns true, I will then like to set the clipboard text to a different string and then get and display the new value on my console. Here's my Clipbpard.h

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <cstring>

namespace Diall_ClipBoard_catch
{
    class ClipBoard
    {
    private:
        ::HANDLE dHDat;
        ::std::string tmpstringsign;
        bool isopen;
        char* dHbuffer;
        char* dHbuffertemp;
        char* dNtoken;
    public:
        ClipBoard(void)
        {
            this->dHbuffer = const_cast <char*>("");
            this->dHbuffertemp = const_cast <char*>("");
            this->tmpstringsign = "dnb_4554_2102";
            this->isopen = false;
        };
        ~ClipBoard(void)
        {

        }
        char* GetData(void)
        {
            this->Start();
            if (this->isopen)
            {
                this->dHDat = ::GetClipboardData(CF_TEXT);

                if (this->dHDat)
                {
                    this->dHbuffer = (char*)::GlobalLock(this->dHDat);

                    if (::std::strcmp(this->dHbuffertemp, this->dHbuffer) != 0 && this->dHbuffer != "" && this->dHbuffer != NULL)
                    {
                        this->dHbuffertemp = this->dHbuffer;
                        //::std::cout << this->dHbuffer << "\n";
                        return this->dHbuffer;
                    }

                    ::GlobalUnlock(this->dHDat);
                }
                CloseClipboard();
                this->isopen = FALSE;
                ::Sleep(1000);
            }
        }
        void SetData(void)
        {
            const char* data = this->dHbuffer;
            const char* newstring = "Hello World";
            const size_t len = strlen(data) + 1;
            HGLOBAL hMem = GlobalAlloc(GMEM_MOVEABLE, len);
            memcpy(GlobalLock(hMem), data, len);
            GlobalUnlock(hMem);
            if (!OpenClipboard(NULL))
                {
                    return;
                }
            if(strlen(data) + 1 == 8 && (data.at(0) == 1 || data.at(0) == 7)){
                EmptyClipboard();
                SetClipboardData(CF_TEXT, hMem);
            }
            CloseClipboard();
            this->isopen = TRUE;
        }
    private:
        void Start(void)
        {
            if (!OpenClipboard(NULL))
            {
                return;
            }
            this->isopen = true;
        }
    };
}
```

And here is my m main.cpp

```
#include "Clipboard.h"

int main()
{
    ::Diall_ClipBoard_catch::ClipBoard* clipboard = new Diall_ClipBoard_catch::ClipBoard();
    int temp1 = 0, temp2 = 0;
    EmptyClipboard();
    while (1)
    {
        temp1 = GetClipboardSequenceNumber();
        if (temp1!= temp2)
        {
            clipboard->SetData();
            std::cout << clipboard->GetData() << std::endl;
        }

        temp2 = temp1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I managed to make it work without the SetData() by only calling the GetData(). the issue I got with that is that it returns the string copied to the clipboard and after that I can't get any data from the clipbord i.e it works only once when I run the program but I want it to be continuous for every string copied and meets the condition.

Now I changed data.at(0) to data[0] and my code was able to compile with no error. The issue I am getting now is, my conditions always return false even when it should return true. What I am trying to do is check to see if the clipboard data is an 8 character long string and it starts with either a "1" or a "3" but it always returns false.
I proceeded to changing

```
const char* data = this->dHbuffer;
```

to

```
const char* data[] = this->dHbuffer;
```

Something else I noticed is that strlen(data) returns 1 as it's value. My question now is; Is there a way to get the actual length of the string as a string and not the size of the array?

but I got an error;
**Clipboard.h|55|error: initializer fails to determine size of 'data'|**
p.s I am an absolute beginner with c++ and I just started taking classes just last week. I do not fully understand the concept of classes in c++

Comment: There are missing functions like EmptyClipboard() and GetClipboardSequenceNumber(). Do you know what a debugger is and how to use it?

Comment: You appear to just assign the pointer from the clipboard data. Is that correct? Do you not have to copy the actual data and not just assign the pointer to it?

Comment: Yes that is what I am trying to do and I have specified the arguments in my SetData function

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you've defined `data` here as

```
const char* data = this->dHbuffer;
```

which means that `data` is a `const char*`, a raw pointer to some characters. However, later on you write

```
if (strlen(data) + 1 == 8 && (data.at(0) == 1 || data.at(0) == 7)) {
                              ^^^^^^^^^^         ^^^^^^^^^^
```

which treats `data` as though it were a `std::string`. To fix this, instead write

```
if (strlen(data) + 1 == 8 && (data[0] == 1 || data[0] == 7)) {
                              ^^^^^^^         ^^^^^^^
```

It may be the case that, independently, there are other errors here, but this is the proximal compiler error that you're running into.

Comment: Thank you so much, this was very helpful but I still have an issue.
Now I get the string returned but it seems my conditions are wrong as strlen() returns false even though I have an 8 character long string in my clipboard that starts with "1". Also, I can only get the data in my clipboard before I run the program but can not copy or paste anything after that. Thank you.

Comment: It might be good to post that as a follow-up question, since this answer is limited just to the initial issue you had.